# Reusing template over multiple domains

Tags: templates, grails, reusability

I am trying to re-using templates over multiple domains. 
Template looks like this:

```
<div id="emailEntry">
    <Table>
        <tr class="prop">
        <td valign="top" class="name">
            <label for="email" id="email"><g:message code="default.email.label" default="Primary e-mail address* :" id="email" /></label>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: instanceToUse, field: 'email', 'errors')}">  
            <g:textField name="email" value="${instanceToUse?.email}"/> 
        </td>
    </tr>       
    </Table>
</div>
```

and my view calls this template like this:

```
<g:render template="/templates/frmEmailTableEntry" />
```

Both of my class "customer" and "employee" have email attributes. 
so my question is, if I want to reuse template "frmEmailTableEntry" for class "**customer**" and "**employee**", what should I put to "**instanceToUse**" in template. 
I read about rendering with var declared, but I am not so sure how to pass this. Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out custom taglibs.  Their best fitted for this type of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really matter what you put in the template. If you leave it just as is you could use it in other gsp's like this:

```
//say the instance you wish to use is "customerInstance"
<g:render template="/templates/frmEmailTableEntry" model="[instanceToUse: customerInstance]" />
```

That passes the `customerInstance` into the `${instanceToUse}` variable in the template.